# Why my c++ code is going to an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, g++, infinite-loop

I wrote a C++ code for LBM to solve diffusion equation and I compiled it in g++ in Ubuntu. It compiled just fine but when I try to execute the program, it does not come to an end. I thought the program is having an infinite loop somehow, but I couldn't solve where? Thank you guys in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int Lx = 100;
    const int Ly = 100;
    int sMod = 8; //speed model 
    float f[sMod][Lx+1][Ly+1];
    float rho[Lx+1][Ly+1];
    float feq, sum;
    float x[Lx+1];
    float y[Ly+1];
    float csq, alpha, omega,Tw;
    float w[9] = {4./9., 1./9., 1./9., 1./9., 1./9., 1./36., 1./36., 1./36., 1./36.};
    int i, j, dt, dx, k, dy; 

    FILE * mFile;
    dt = 1.0;
    dx = 1.0;
    dy = dx;

    x[0] = 0.0;
    for(i = 1; i < Lx; i++){
        x[i] = x[i-1] + dx;
        }
    y[0] = 0.0;
    for(j = 1; j < Ly; j++){
        y[j] = y[j-1] + dy;
        }

    Tw = 1.0;
    csq = (dx * dx)/(dt * dt);
    alpha = 0.25;
    omega = 1.0/((3.*alpha/(dt*csq))+0.5);
    cout << "csq: " << csq << ", omega: " << omega << endl;
    int mstep = 2; 

    for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
        {
        rho[i][j] = 0.0;
        //cout << "1: " << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;
        }
    }
        //cout << "5: " << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;

    for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
    {   
            //cout << "2: " << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;
        for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
        {
            //cout << "3: " << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;
            for(k = 0; k <= sMod; k++)
            {
                            //cout << "4: " << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;
                f[k][i][j] = w[k] * rho[i][j];
                if(i == 0){
                    f[k][i][j] = w[k] * Tw;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
            cout << "2: " << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;
    for(k = 1; k <= mstep; k++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
        {
            for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
            {   
                sum = 0.0;
                for(k = 0;k <= sMod; k++)
                {
                    sum = sum + f[k][i][j];
                }
                rho[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }

        cout << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;

    for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
    {   
        for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
        {
            for(k = 0;k <= sMod; k++)
            {
                feq = w[k] * rho[i][j];
                f[k][i][j] = omega * feq + (1. - omega) * f[k][i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    /*-------
    streaming
    --------*/

    for(j = Ly; i >= 0; j--)
    {
        for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
        {       
            f[2][i][j] = f[2][i][j-1];
            f[6][i][j] = f[6][i+1][j-1];
        }
    }

    for(j = Ly; i >= 0; j--)
    {
        for(i = Lx; i >= 0; i--)
        {                       
            f[1][i][j] = f[1][i-1][j]; //right to left
            f[5][i][j] = f[5][i-1][j-1];
        }
    }


    for(j = 0; i <= Ly; j--)
    {
        for(i = Lx; i >= 0; i--)
        {   
            f[4][i][j] = f[4][i][j+1]; 
            f[8][i][j] = f[8][i-1][j+1];
        }
    }

    for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
    {   
        for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
        {   
            f[3][i][j] = f[3][i+1][j]; 
            f[7][i][j] = f[7][i+1][j+1];
        }
    }

    //boundary conditions

    for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
    {
        f[1][0][j] = w[1]*Tw + w[3]*Tw - f[3][0][j];
        f[5][0][j] = w[5]*Tw + w[7]*Tw - f[7][0][j];
        f[8][0][j] = w[8]*Tw + w[6]*Tw - f[6][0][j];
        f[3][Lx][j] = -f[1][Lx][j];
        f[6][Lx][j] = -f[8][Lx][j];
        f[7][Lx][j] = -f[5][Lx][j];
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
    {
        f[4][i][Ly] = -f[2][i][Ly];
        f[7][i][Ly] = -f[5][i][Ly];
        f[8][i][Ly] = -f[6][i][Ly];
        f[1][i][0] = f[1][i][1];
        f[2][i][0] = f[2][i][1];
        f[3][i][0] = f[3][i][1];
        f[4][i][0] = f[4][i][1];
        f[5][i][0] = f[5][i][1];
        f[6][i][0] = f[6][i][1];
        f[7][i][0] = f[7][i][1];
        f[8][i][0] = f[8][i][1];
    }
    }

    for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
    {   
        for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
        {   
            sum = 0.0;
            for(k = 0;k <= sMod; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + f[k][i][j];
            }
        rho[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }

    cout << rho[0][Ly/2] << endl;

    mFile = fopen("lbmdiffusiond2q9.csv","w");
    fprintf(mFile,"\t\t----TITLE= D2Q9 RESULTS----\n");
    fprintf(mFile," VARIABLES = RHO\n");
    //myfile << "ZONE " << "I=" << Lx+1 << " J=" << Ly+1 << " F=POINT" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= Ly; j++)
        {   
    //myfile << (dx/Lx) * i << " " << (dy/Ly) * j << " " << rho[i][j] << endl;
            fprintf(mFile,"%.6f ",rho[i][j]);   
        }
        fprintf(mFile,"\n");
    }   
    fclose(mFile);      

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I normally do in this situation, is to remove all loops and then check each one at a time to see which one(s) are an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(j = Ly; i >= 0; j--)
{
    for(i = 0; i <= Lx; i++)
    {       
        f[2][i][j] = f[2][i][j-1];
        f[6][i][j] = f[6][i+1][j-1];
    }
}
```

Your loop index is over `j`, but your loop condition is over `i`, with an inner loop
that assigns to `i`.  This occurs in several of the loops.

Comment: thanks. I corrected the code and compiled it again, but it still goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: There's also a place where you use `k` as both an outer and inner loop index, did you fix that too?  Using more meaningful variable names, rather than i,j,k etc., can help you avoid some of these sorts of bugs.  Also, it would have been fairly trivial to use a debugger or even some print statements to identify where the program was getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This bit here seems to be your problem:

```
for(j = 0; i <= Ly; j--)
{
    for(i = Lx; i >= 0; i--)
    {   
        f[4][i][j] = f[4][i][j+1]; 
        f[8][i][j] = f[8][i-1][j+1];
    }
}
```

The outer loop starts at 0, decreases the counter, and the loop condition doesn't check the counter.  In fact, the loop condition is guaranteed to remain true forever if it was true before the loop, because the inner loop will end with `i == 0`.